# SCORM Exit Button From Android

Tags: android, exit, scorm, articulate-storyline

Im trying to exit from SCORM using EXIT Button which is displayed at the end of scorm. The parameter that is passed during the exit is "***cmi.core.exit***" which gives a value "**suspend**".

The SCORM course is running perfectly on SCORM cloud and exit button is working fine on Web APP.

In Android, when Exit button is clicked, LMSFinish is called with "" (Blank) paramter, and nothing happens while the same call is done in web and exit button works fine.

Im using SCORM1_2 and everything is working fine with scorm on android except **EXIT** part.

Any Solution or any suggestions for the same

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note that an Exit button is not part of the Android paradigm because the user can always press the Home button to leave an app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your looking at this using HTML5 rather than the Android app. You could try force close of the tab rather than the built in close function has been a fix we've used:

Fire Javascript on exit button:

```
if(window.CloseWindow && typeof window.CloseWindow === "function" ) {
      window.CloseWindow();
} else {
   window.close();
}
```